# Ifstream-object outside while-loop

Tags: c++, ifstream

How do I best place the ifstream-object outside the while-loop? If I do as follows the file is only opened once - next time all data is set to zero.

```
 ifstream fil("prices.txt");


 while (running) {

   // code .... menusystem
   // show the file. 

 }
```

I know it works if I put the syntax within the while loop but I don't think its a good idea to call this stream-object continiously - am I right?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Why don't you read the file once and save the results in a data structure?

Comment: Too vague... what are you doing with the ifstream?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I best place the ifstream-object outside the while-loop?

If you work with the data from that file inside your `while` loop, it's placed all right.

> If I do as follows the file is only opened once - next time all data is set to zero.

It's not clear what data you're talking about. Since you use `ifstream`, you open the file for reading, and you cannot erase data in it.

Probably you didn't provide all necessary information to judge about your problem.